# Find the summation, given a few numbers of the sequence

Tags: summation, power-series

If a have a sequence such as the following:

$$a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots$$

How can I find the summation representation for it, assuming it converges?
I have searched a bit on MathExchange and found this [Get sequence given the first few elements of the sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293446/get-sequence-given-the-first-few-elements-of-the-sequence). However, the sequences presented in OEIS are just integer ones. What about rationals? How should I proceed?

Thanks

**EDIT**

For example, let's say we have the following sequence:
$$1, -\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, -\frac{1}{7}, \cdots$$
As we can see, the summation can be rewritten as

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\lbrace \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \right\rbrace$$

Which is the summation representation for the sequence above. The question is about how I can find a sigma sum for an arbitrary sequence. It is not necessary knowing its value, its sum.

Comment: There is no universal method for summing a convergent series even if you have a convenient closed form for the terms, is that what you are asking?

Comment: Should say:  all OEIS does is to attempt to match the given terms of your sequence with one or more of the sequences it is familiar with.  That's a great thing, of course, but it can't spot things it doesn't already know about and the patterns it does recognize may not persist.

Comment: @lulu No, it is not. Take a look at the edits made, now it's clear, I think....

Comment: Not clear to me.  That particular example famously sums to $\frac {\pi}4$.  One can get it by integrating $\frac 1{1+x^2}$ from $0$ to $1$.  not sure how you hope to generalize that.  And what can you mean by saying that you want a "sigma sum" but don't care about getting an actual value for the sum?

Comment: @lulu sorry, I'm not an english native speaker... Let's see how can I explain you this. First, I knew the value of that sum, this is why I used it as na example. Now, about the question itself: I have a sequence and I want to know which sigma sum representation fits for that sequence. For example, if the numbers in the example were all positive, then the sigma sum representation would be: $\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}$.

Comment: Still not clear.  I think, but really I am just guessing, that you aren't asking about a sum at all, rather you just want to know how you write down a simple closed formula for the terms in a sequence given the first few.  Unfortunately, there is no way to do that.  The suggestion you were told, to use OEIS, is about as good as it gets.  If you have rational numbers you can apply OEIS to the numerator and denominators separately (though cancellation of common factors can make that very difficult or impossible).

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much it. Sorry, I want to find a closed form for a sequence. Thanks a lot. However, @lulu, do you  know any sequence of numbers except Fibonnaci's and Lucas'?